# How to change errorText background color in Flutter InputDecoration

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to validate my TextFormField using the validator.
It works, but I'm not able to change the background color of this error text.
I am already trying out the errorStyle, but this option is only able to style the text.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      elevation: 3,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
      child: TextFormField(
        autocorrect: false,
        obscureText: this.isPassword != null ? this.isPassword : false,
        controller: controller,
        autofillHints: (this.autofillHint != null) ? [ this.autofillHint ] : [],
        style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.getBlackColor(context)),
        keyboardType: keyboardType,
        validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Field is required' : null,
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          filled: true,
          fillColor: (AppColors.isDarkMode(context)) ? AppColors.darkModeWitheAccent : Colors.white,
          hintText: hintText,
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          ),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.blue, width: 2.0),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: result]

Comment: have you tried wrapping your `TextFormField` with `Container()` and then giving `Container()` a color?

Comment: It's working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the color of parent container, in this case it's `Material` widget

```dart
Material(
  elevation: 3,
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
  color: Colors.black,
  child: TextFormField(
    autocorrect: false,
    validator: (value) =>
    (value?.isEmpty ?? false) ? 'Field is required' : null,
    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      filled: true,
      fillColor: Colors.amber,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Sample: https://www.dartpad.dev/777892f64e0aa5d36e0995ed5ca00f68?null_safety=true

[image]